# Set sort on first column as default in TOAD

Tags: oracle, sorting, toad

I'm using Toad for Oracle 12.5 and a little thing anoy me : when I look into the "Data" tab of a table, the row order is all jumbled up.

On any other DB software I used (SQL developper, phpmyadmin, etc), the default data view would retur the rows ordered by the primary key

So, I would like it to automaticly by default sort the data in the "Data" tab of each table to the first column, or even better, to the table primary key.

I've looked in the options but I can't see anything related to this.

Have some of you had the same problem ?

Comment: You only want that until you open that tab for the first time on a table with 100 million rows...

Answer (score 3):

No oracle client that I have seen ever tacks an "order by" onto a statement on its own accord. It returns what the query returns in the order (or lack thereov) that it receives it.

Now it may LOOK ordered if the rows were inserted in order, but that is a fluke. Period.

And frankly, I'd be upset if a UI arbitrarily added expensive sorts to my queries unless I specifically told it to.

I have some BIG tables. presuming that I want the UI to take the time to scan  the index and grab the lowest PK values just because I opened the DATA tab? No. Dear me - NO!

If I want it ordered, I will open the sort/filter dialog and specify so, or click on the appropriate column header to sort the results.

**ADDITION:**
If there ARE some tables where you want this behaviour (I can see the convenience if checking code tables for example), then use the sort/filter dialog on the data grid for that table to set an order by and TOAD will remember that setting for that table in this schema until you remove it. So you CAN set this behaviour where you want and not deal with the performance aspects where you don't.